# How do I install an icon with an underscore in its name with xgd-menu?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, terminal, icons

The image file is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q9VaP.png), named it 'An_Icon.png' and saved it to ~/Desktop . I used the following commands to install it to my menus:

```
xdg-desktop-icon install --novendor /home/$(whoami)/Desktop/An_Icon.png
```

If I edit a .desktop launcher and set the icon value to 'An_Icon' or 'An_Icon.png', nothing happens, but if I named it as just 'Icon.png' and installed it, the icon would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
xdg-icon-resource install --novendor 48 An_Icon.png
```

This will copy the icon under `~/.local/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/apps` most likely and make it available for launchers.

Uninstalling is done with:

```
xdg-icon-resource uninstall --size 48 An_Icon
```